Time series : Is SARIMA(p, 0, q)(P, 0, Q) a non-stationary model?
If the data is well explained without any differencing or seasonal differencing but requires some seasonal AR and MA terms, can we say that the data is stationary? I thought SARIMA was designed to handle data with seasonal patterns, so if any of the P, D, or Q parameters are greater than 0, it means we are assuming the data is non-stationary due to seasonality.
Does the statement "build a model for a certain time series data with regression with stationary errors" mean that the regression should explain the trend and seasonal parts using (1, t, t^2, sin, cos ...), and only ARMA(p, q) should be used to explain the stationary error part?

Deterministic seasonality implies nonstationarity, but stochastic seasonality due to P and Q from SARIMA does not.

Thank you for taking the time to answer. It helped me a lot.
